# Reintegrate files into subfolder of an GIT repository

Tags: git

There is a `GIT` repository (`REPO1`). Long time ago it had the following layout:

```
bin
    file.sh
src
    file.cpp
```

Then *bin* was migrated to `CVS` (`REPO2`). Layouts became:

`REPO1`

```
src
    file.cpp
```

`REPO2`

```
file.sh
```

Now I want to move *file.sh* back to *bin* subfolder of `REPO1` with its history. I migrated `CVS` to new `GIT` repository `REPO3` using `cvs2git`.

Histories of repos are:

```
REPO1    REPO3
N          X
|          |
|          |
D          |
|          |
O2        O'2
|          |
O1        O'1
```

- *D* - commit when `bin` was removed from `REPO1`.
- *O1*, *O2* - common commits. They have *O'1* and *O'2* siblings in `REPO3` but with different commit id's (file tree is changed).

Now I want to have the following history:

```
M
| \
N  X
|  |
D  |
| /
O2
|
O1
```

- *M* - merge commit

I tried to use `git subtree -P bin REPO3` but it duplicated history of *file.sh* in period when the file lived in `REPO1`.

```
M
| \
N  X
|  |
D  |
|  |
O2 O'2
|  |
O1 O'1
```

Then I tried to use `git checkout -b temp_branch O2; git cherry-pick O'2..X` to get only "new" commits from `REPO3` but this fails due to different layout of `REPO3` (there is no *bin* folder).

Maybe there is more standard way to accomplish my task? Or I miss some step that would help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cvs2git generate file in `fast-import` format. It is relatively simple format that can be modified with text tools, like sed. Try modify all paths inside fast-import and add `bin/` path prefix.

Description of fast-import format can be found here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fast-import